# Lenovo shutdown, sleep and hibernate issues

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo laptop (Model: B590). It's pretty old and I'm having issues with it.

I can't shut it down. When I try to do so, the screen turns off, but the lights stay on.

Also, when I put it to sleep, it won't wake up. The same thing happens for hibernation.

I've tested reinstalling Windows, but that didn't work. I also tried installing Windows 7, but in that case shutting down causes it to freeze.

Right now I'm using Windows 10 and still have the problem. I want to fix the issue, but I don't know how. Any solutions?

I tried the Fast Startup thing, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest the following two options:

1. Confirm that you have installed Windows is the official original, if not, recommend the installation of Windows official original, and then go to Lenovo to download device drivers, and then install them, and then try to see if there are any problems.
2. Since you use the computer version is very old, within the scope of tolerance, I suggest you go to Lenovo official outlets to pay to refresh the BIOS, try again to see if the problem is solved.