# Lenovo Laptop Shutdown, sleep and hibernate issues

Tags: laptop, sleep, shutdown, hibernate, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo B590 laptop. Its old. I'm having a issue in it.

Windows 10:
When I shutdown the screen turns off but the lights stay on. When I sleep, it doesn't wake up and when I hibernate it, it doesn't wake up too.

The same behavior goes for Windows 8.

On Windows 7, the behavior is same except the shutdown one, when I shut it down it gets stuck on the "Shutting down" dialogue

I want to fix this issue, lots of people have it but I found no solution. I have tried turning off Fast Startup, no solution still.

I have read a guy's post on [Lenovo shutdown, sleep and hibernate issues](https://superuser.com/questions/1351217/lenovo-shutdown-sleep-and-hibernate-issues)
he have the same issue but in the post, there's no answer that works for me.

Help is appreciated.